# Conjugation of upper triangular matrices in $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $T_1$, $T_2$, and $Q$ be elements of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$.  Suppose $T_1$ and $T_2$ are conjugate, and $T_1$,  $T_2$, and $QT_1Q^{-1}$ are all upper triangular.  Must $QT_2Q^{-1}$ be upper triangular as well?

I can find no counterexamples.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. Here is a counterexample. Denote
$$
I = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad J = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}, \quad P = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}.
$$
Take
$$
T_1 = \pmatrix{J & 0\\0 & I}, \quad T_2 = \pmatrix{I&0\\0&J}, \quad Q = \pmatrix{I & 0\\0 & P}.
$$